# How to allow only a word in EditText?

Tags: java, android

I am making a dictionary in Android and I want to allow user to enter only one word which consists of only letters in EditText.

How can I do so?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I'd look into EditText validation or regex to handle this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you can set this in the xml by just adding in the `editext`

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Comment: I prefer this one, it's nice and simple.

Comment: But it doesn't limit EditText to take one word only?

Comment: It essentially does, it doesn't allow spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it programmatically. You can include the space in the regex:

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.youredittext);
Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
Matcher ms = ps.matcher(yourEditText.getText().toString());
boolean bs = ms.matches();
if(!bs){
    //Toast Re-Entry
}
```